# Does creating a new variable use up more memory than instantiating the variable?

Tags: variables, memory-management, variable-assignment, instantiation

sorry if the title is a little 'off', couldn't think of a better title for it.

Anyway, the question is I have some code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
{
    int dice = rnd.Next(1, 7);
}
```

Basically this will generate a random number 50 times, the question I have is does instantiating the variable use up more memory than just changing the variable 'dice'

So the code would be like this:

```
int dice;
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
{
    dice = rnd.Next(1, 7);
}
```

Just curios to if it does use up more memory or not to re-assign the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is the same, compiler will just reserve enough space to store the value of "dice", regardless of where it's declared.

Just keep your variable in inner-most scope you can and that's it.